# What is "ölsaurem Alkali"

Tags: terminology

I read a technical German book that refers to "ölsaurem Alkali" which apparently means "oleic acid alkali". How could it be both an acid and an alkali?

Comment: Can you cite the book?

Comment: At a guess, I would think it means a salt of oleic acid

Comment: Actually if you google "ölsaurem Alkali" there's too many German books referring to this term, so I guess there isn't any need for a citation @Pritt ;-)

Comment: @GaurangTandon Well, OP's should support their claims, so there is such need.

Answer (score 11):

They were writing it fancy in old times.
Sodium acetate would have been "essigsaures Natrium", potassium sulfate "schwefelsaures Kalium" and so on.

Therefor, "ölsaures Alkali" is an alkali salt of oleic acid (Ölsäure).